# Increase Resharper Font Size in Unit Test Runner window

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I've been using ReSharper for years and have managed to tweak most of the settings to my liking.  I'm getting older and my eyes aren't as good as they used to be, so I have been increasing my font sizes.  I have been able to tweak most of them (including ReSharper specific ones) in Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors.

However, I have not been able to find the setting that controls the font in the Unit Test Runner output Window.  For me, it is downright *tiny*.  Come to think of it, most of ReSharper's own windows' fonts are tiny, but that is the one that is currently bugging me.

Anyone know how to adjust these fonts?  Scaling up my font size system wide is not an option.

Currently using VS 2013 with ReSharper 8.2

Thanks

Comment: This is no longer an issue now using ReSharper 10 in VS 2015.